# grep/sed not found error, not in $path

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm a unix newbie here and I have a unix command I'm trying to run but I get a "GREP: not found" error. I looked at $PATH and didn't see anything resembling grep (not sure if thats what i'm looking for either though)...

The command is this:

```
testabcd=$(bteq << EOF 2>&1  |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
 .LOGON server/user, pass
 DATABASE schema;
 .set width 2000;
  .set titledashes off;
 SELECT '>'||COUNT(*) FROM schema1.table1;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
 EOF)

echo "The count is: " $testabcd
```

then I get these errors:

```
-ksh: SED: not found (No such file or directory)
>echo "The count is: " $testvarabcd
THE DATA IS:
>-ksh: GREP: not found
*** Error: The following error was encountered on the output file.
*** Error: Broke pipe
*** Warning: Canceling the rest of the output
```

if grep is not in PATH, do I need to install it? If not, can I set the path in the command and how do I search where the grep path is??

Comment: Can you do `which grep`? And paste the output here..

Comment: Your error messages show all CAPS for the commands. `GREP` is not same `grep`!

Comment: Blue Moon: Thanks! that was it!

Answer (score -1):

replace grep with /bin/grep and sed with /bin/sed.
ultimately you need to add /bin to your path.

do you like ksh? In my experience, csh, tcsh, or bash are
more commonly used. Using one of those may give you a better path.
Then you would not need to edit your path.

the file that contains you path is a hidden file (it has a . in front
of the file name) in your home directory. try ls .* in your home directory.
Even better, try

/bin/grep PATH .*

this will locate the file with the PATH variable.

Comment: ksh is fully compliant with POSIX sh -- in fact, the POSIX sh standard was written based on ksh as it existed at the time. Also, recommending tcsh (which is _not_ POSIX compliant in any way, shape or form) is generally bad advice; see also  http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Comment: (Also, as the error message made clear, and has since been acknowledged in the comments, the problem was the user's scripts capitalizing `GREP` as a separate command).